# Case flow missing / disappeared

Tags: casemilestone, path

I've had a few customer layouts with the attached gone missing, any ideas where this maybe setup? It's not happening to all customers just a few, and no one has changed any settings.

[image: With Case Flow][image: Missing Case Flow]

---

As you can see from the first image (RED arrow), the tabs are there but with the second image (Orange arrow) the tabs have disappeared. This only happens with some customers, in the cases option.[image: With Flow Tabs][image: Without Flow Tabs]

Comment: Can you please elaborate more ? The picture does not indicate clearly what is missing ! Draw a circle or an arrow for some one to understand!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please don't use Answers for additional detail - instead [edit] your post to include it.  Your post mentions Flow but in your screenshot you are pointing to the Path feature, which is not a flow.  Please clarify what is specific feature you mean.  If this is a Path, have you checked the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.path_overview.htm&type=5)?

Answer (score -1):

1. Kindly Check if the user's in profile or permission set is there Read/Read+Write access to the Status Field on Case
2. Also do check the Page Layout assignment to the profiles of the user who are not able to view the status path tabs on the case page layout.
3. Since Even if user has access to the status field but you may have assigned a different page layout which does not the case status path tabs in it ,to the user's profile